# Can someone explain this behaviour for virtual function?

Tags: c++, copy-constructor

I know about the basic concept of virtual function and run-time call. But i tried 
running some piece of code which confused me

```
   class A {
   public:
    A& operator=(char) {
      cout << "A& A::operator=(char)" << endl;
      return *this;
    }
    virtual A& operator=(const A&) {
      cout << "A& A::operator=(const A&)" << endl;
      return *this;
    }
   };

   class B : public A {
   public:
      B& operator=(char) {
        cout << "B& B::operator=(char)" << endl;
        return *this;
      }

      virtual B& operator=(const B&) {
        cout << "B& B::operator=(const B&)" << endl;
        return *this;
      }
   };

   int main() {
    B b1;
    B b2;
    A* ap1 = &b1;
    A* ap2 = &b1;
    *ap1 = 'z';
    *ap2 = b2; 
   }
```

Running this program give me the following output:-

```
   A& A::operator=(char)  //expected output
   A& A::operator=(const A&) //Why this Output?  in case of  *ap2 = b2;
```

`b2` is an object of `B` type but still it goes in virtual `A& operator=(const A&)`
and not virtual `B& operator=(const B&)`. Why is this so ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `virtual B& operator=(const B&)` does not override `virtual A& operator=(const A&)`; the arguments are different.

Comment: Chalesworth so is it that a pointer type matters during the function call and not the kind of object is that pointer pointing to , Which actually happens in case of virtual function? Because here ap2 is a pointer type of A but pointing to an object of B type ? I am wrong somewhere?

Comment: @Ritesh: In the line `*ap2 = b2`, the compile-time type of `*ap2` is `A`.  So the compiler can only consider (virtual) member functions that are present in the interface that `A` presents.

Answer (score 2):

For a derived class function to override Base class function, the derived class function needs to have the exact same function prototype(exception: covariant return types are allowed).

The `=` operator in derived class `B` here does not have same function prototype as `=` in Base class `A`, and hence it does not override the Base class `=`.

The only `=` operator available is the one which is called.

Answer (score 2):

For a function to be considered an override the signature has to match the version in tha base class exactly (well, the return type may be covariant if a pointer or a reference is returned). That is, you would need to define

```
B& B::operator= (A const&)
```

to override the version from the base class. Note that for input parameters in overriding functions it wouldn't make sense to be covariant because you can't guarantee that the base class version is called with a derived object in a context using only the base class. If anything parameters to an overriding function could be contravariant but C++ doesn't support this.

Answer (score 2):

Here in the derived class the function is taking B whereas in base class its taking A. So, basically its not being overridden as the function arguments are different.

> Also note that the return type in case of overriding may be different as in your case you are returning reference of A in base and reference of B in derived.
>   virtual Base& func(const Base&)
>   virtual Derived& func(const Base&) 
>   This is valid form of overriding